# Why can't SQL server see the parameter I've added?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to call a parameterized stored procedure from a console app. Here is the code:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection);

connection.Open();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Account", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = accountNumber;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"Prod-{empIdNumber}";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get an exception returned that the stored procedure expects an `@EmployeeId` parameter which was not provided. I have double checked the spelling.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

edit: I should add, that the stored procedure works fine when called directly.

Comment: Shouldn't EmployeeId be integer?

Comment: Yes, but this is what the sproc expects :(

Comment: @will the sproc wants a varchar?

Comment: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`? At the moment you're just running the *text* `MyStoredProcedure`. It doesn't know to make use of any parameters since *text* can contain any number of statements which may depend on different combinations of parameters that have bee provided.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, put that sh!t in an answer so I can check it off!